# How to make sure clients update their browser cache when my website is updated?

Tags: http, cache, static-content

I am using the `HTTP 1.1` [`Cache-Control`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.9) header to implement client-side caching. Since I update my website only once a month I would like the `CSS` and `JS` files to be cached for 30 days with `Cache-Control: max-age=2592000`. The problem is that the 30-day period defined by `Cache-Control` doesn't coincide with the website update cycle, it starts from the moment the users visit the site and ends 30 days later, which means an update could occur in the meantime and users would be running with outdated content for a while, which could break the rendering of the website if for instance the `HTML` and `CSS` no longer match.

**How can I perform client-side caching of content for periods of several days but somehow get users to refresh their `CSS/JS` files after the website has been updated?**

One solution I could think of is that if website updates can be schedule, the `max-age` returned by the server could be decreased every day accordingly so that no matter when people visit the website, the end of caching period would coincide with the update of the website, but changing the server configuration every day goes against one of my sysadmin principles (once it's running, don't touch it).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add [fingerprints/hashes](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/caching#LeverageBrowserCaching) your CSS and JS URLs and set far-future Expires/Cache-Control headers.

This is also the technique that Rails [Asset Pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#what-is-fingerprinting-and-why-should-i-care) uses.

Comment: this is the best way